# Remove legend key from plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Probably a very simple question for ppl familiar with `ggplot2`:  how can I suppress/remove plotting of the legend key? Here, for example, I'd like to plot just the tiles but not the `value` key. What needs to be added or changed to the code?

```
df <- expand.grid(X1 = 1:10, X2 = 1:10)
df$value <- df$X1 * df$X2

ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

Comment: `+ theme(legend.position = "none")` will also remove the legend all together

Comment: `theme(legend.position = "none")` works -- thanks!

Comment: Just for completeness, if you want to remove a specific legend, you can use `guides(fill = "none")`, wherein 'fill' indicates what legend you want to remove.